# How to get particular content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have used ajax to get some data or whole page.

Now what I want is data of particular div class or id how to get that.

For eg. I am getting some thing like this.

```
<html>
 <body>

 <div id="a">

 <div id="b">

  <p> abc</p>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
```

And I want only the data between div with id="a"

ie.

```
 <div id="b">

  <p> abc</p>
 </div>
```

how to get this using jQuery and ajax

Comment: Is there any way to select only particular part from the given data.

Comment: $('#a').html() would do this. or i didn't understand the problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `id`

```
$('#a').html();   //gives the html
```

You can get the content by using [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)   function

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it like this using jQuery:

```
var result = $('#a').innerHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

store the response into a variable and use find method

var res = urAjax response;

$(res).find("div");

Answer (score 0):

When you have your AJAX response loaded in variable, you can use `filter()` or `find()` jQuery function to select element you want.

```
var a='<div id="a" class="c">abc</div><div id="b">ABC</div>';
var res = $(a).filter("#a")[0];
$('#container').append(res);

a='<span><div id="a" class="c">abc</div><div id="b">ABC</div></span>';
var res = $(a).find("#b")[0];
$('#container').append(res);
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lopisan/mLmSu/1/)